# Combinatorial Proof of Identity $\binom {n}{k} = (k+1)\binom {n-1}{k}+(n-k)\binom {n-1}{k-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, recursive-algorithms

How do I build a combinatorial proof of the following recursion:

$$\binom {n}{k} = (k+1)\binom {n-1}{k}+(n-k)\binom {n-1}{k-1}$$

I'm having really big difficulties in finding the right way to realize the solution...I'm not even sure if the problem is solvable by the means of combinatorial reasoning...

Professor reminded us to use similar way of thinking as applied in the case of Stirling numbers of first and second kind...

Comment: what is $S(n,k)$?

Comment: or see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427eikhdbrkvh3)...

Comment: As per WA link above, this identity doesn't hold.

Comment: I've also come to the same conclusion, I think I'll argue with my professor over this... Thanks for your comments!

Comment: I think the identity you're meant to solve is: $\dbinom{n}{k} = \dbinom{n-1}{k-1} + \dbinom{n-1}{k}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a combinatorial identity! For example
$$\binom{7}{6}=7 \neq 7\binom{6}{6}+1\binom{6}{5}=7+6=13$$
Then, you have $$(k+1)\binom {n-1}{k}+(n-k)\binom {n-1}{k-1} = (k+1)\left(\frac{n-2k}{n}\binom{n}{k}+ \binom {n-1}{k-1}\right)+(n-k)\binom {n-1}{k-1}=\frac{k(n-2k)}{n}\binom{n}{k}+k\binom {n-1}{k-1}+\frac{n-2k}{n}\binom{n}{k}+ \binom {n-1}{k-1}+n\binom {n-1}{k-1}-k\binom {n-1}{k-1}=(n-2k)\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\frac{n-2k}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}+(n+1)\binom{n-1}{k-1}=\left(n-2k+\frac{n-2k}{k}+n+1\right)\binom{n-1}{k-1}=\frac{2nk+n-k-2k^2}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}=\frac{2nk+n-k-2k^2}{n}\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{k}\Rightarrow 2nk+n-k-2k^2=n \Rightarrow k=0 \text{ or } k = \frac{2n-1}{2}=n-\frac12$$
The last solution is not valid, as $n \in \Bbb{N} \Rightarrow n-\frac12=k \notin \Bbb{N}$ so $k!$ is not defined. The solution $k=0$ is not acceptable too, as $-1!$ doesn't exist $\to$ there are no solutions $\in \Bbb{N}$